# IEnumerable in LINQ when only one instance of the node

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to query some XML using Linq. I have the following snippet of XML ...

```
<report>
  <invoice>
    <id>A4245</id>
    <date>12-20-2016</date>
    <amount>12.50</amount>
  </invoice>
<report>
```

Here is my model to hold the data

```
public class InvoiceModel
{
  public string InvoiceId { get; set; }
  public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }
  public string InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the LINQ query

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(@"C:\Path\To\data.xml");
InvoiceModel invoice = xml.Descendants("invoice")
                       .Select(x => new InvoiceModel 
                       {
                         InvoiceId = x.Element("id").Value.ToString(),
                         InvoiceDate = x.Element("date").Value.ToString(),
                         InvoiceAmount = x.Element("amount").Value.ToString()
                       });
```

The error I get is ..

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<InvoiceModel>' to 'InvoiceModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

There is only going to be a single invoice in the XML. How do I tell the LINQ query there will only be one instance of the invoice and there is no need for `IEnumerable`?

P.S. I am using all strings for the property values as they are just being used as text and will not be parsed.

Comment: use var....var invoice = xml.Descendants

Comment: I did try `var invoice` originally and it worked but I wanted to return a strongly typed object from the method that contains this code.

Comment: Is there any way to modify the LINQ statement so only one element is returned? I tried using `Single()` and `First()` but the `Select()` is not available after using those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Select()` returns a collection.  If there will only ever be one element in that collection, append:

```
.Single()
```

If there can be more than one and you want the first:

```
.First()
```

If there should be one but might be none:

```
.SingleOrDefault()
```

etc.

There's a variety of logic you can apply, with a variety of extention methods for any `IEnumerable<T>`.  Basically, if you just want one, select just that one from the collection returned by `.Select()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.FirstOrDefault()` to select the only `invoice` element:

```
InvoiceModel invoice = xml.Descendants("invoice")
   .Select(x => new InvoiceModel
   {
       InvoiceId = x.Element("id").Value.ToString(),
       InvoiceDate = x.Element("date").Value.ToString(),
       InvoiceAmount = x.Element("amount").Value.ToString()
   })
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

There is other issues in your code:

- You want to use `XDocument.Load` to load a file, `Parse` is for raw xml.
- The xml is not properly terminated. The last tag should be `</report>`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(@"C:\Path\To\data.xml");
InvoiceModel invoice = xml.Descendants("invoice")
                       .Select(x => new InvoiceModel 
                       {
                         InvoiceId = x.Element("id").Value.ToString(),
                         InvoiceDate = x.Element("date").Value.ToString(),
                         InvoiceAmount = x.Element("amount").Value.ToString()
                       }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `Descendants(...)` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, which then gets converted with `Select` to `IEnumerable<InvoiceModel>`. If you know that there is at most one descendant with the proper name, use `FistsOrDefault()` to retrieve it:

```
InvoiceModel invoice = xml.Descendants("invoice")
    .Select(x => new InvoiceModel {
        InvoiceId = x.Element("id").Value.ToString(),
        InvoiceDate = x.Element("date").Value.ToString(),
        InvoiceAmount = x.Element("amount").Value.ToString()
    }).FirstOrDefault();
// Make sure that you get an invoice
if (invoice == null) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invoice element does not exist in XML document.");
}
```